# Where can I find a list of carriers strings returned by Twilio's carrier lookup?

Tags: python, dictionary, twilio, lookup, carrier

I am starting to test `Twilio's carrier lookup API` (with Python) and I get a `dictionary` return as below:
`print(phone_number.carrier)`

`{'name': '**Sprint Spectrum, L.P**.', 'mobile_network_code': '880','mobile_country_code': '311', 'error_code': None, 'type': 'mobile'}`

Here are some other carrier strings I have had returned:

```
'Verizon Wireless'
'T-Mobile USA, Inc.'
'Cricket Wireless - ATT - SVR'
'T-Mobile USA, Inc.'
'AT&T Wireless'
```

I have these questions:

1. Can anyone point me to a comprehensive list of possible carriers? So far the closest I have found is here: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223182088-What-carriers-are-supported-on-Twilio-short-codes-   but this is insuficient because I would like the exact strings that would be passed back for the carrier name, and I would like to know if Twilio provides a comprehensive carrier lookup list that includes some of the smaller carriers such as cingular...see below example list of gateways:
   https://www.textsendr.com/emailsms.php
2. Does anyone know how to get the EMAIL-to-SMS gateway information (For example, for 'Sprint Spectrum, L.P.' it is "cellnum@messaging.sprintpcs.com").

Thanks and regards,
Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this response back from Twilio support:
*"I'm afraid we don't offer the option to list carriers beforehand. And you are right, we don't include gateway information. "*